# How do I load a javascript file after Jquery.load( )?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, laravel-5

I'm navigating through the site by doing this

```
$('.account-nav a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault(e);
    var url = this.href;
    console.log(url);
    $('.account-nav  a> .account-tab-current').removeClass('account-tab-current');
    $(this).children('.account-tab').addClass('account-tab-current');

    $('#user-page-content').remove();
    $('#user-page-container').load(url + ' #user-page-content').hide().fadeIn('fast');

    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    if (url != window.location){
        window.history.pushState({path: url}, '', url);
    }
```

Problem is, one of the pages contains a script that doesn't get loaded.  that page. I also pass in a php variable. It looks something like this:

```
<div id ='user-page-container>
  <div id ='user-page-content>
    //content with $variable


<script>
    var myVariable =
            '<?php
if (isset($variable)) {
    echo $variable;
}

 //some jquery animation stuff here

?>';

</script>
  </div>
</div>
```

Nothing inside the script get loaded when the html is loaded through jquery.

Comment: how do you load the user-page-container? async? or on siteload?

Comment: $variable is not have any value thats why it is empty inside the script tag. Check its value

Comment: sorry i don't quite understand the question.  I just remove content with $'(content).remove() and then $('#container').load(url, + ' #content')

Comment: yeah I realize $variable is empty.  Not sure how to get it to pass =\

Comment: so I removed the $variable in the script and harcoded it instead.  The script files are still not loading